# Pointing the right direction!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I can bury a part in fearsome.
>   Can make the second letter fly, which is awesome.
>   I can behead, but I ain't no killer.
>   Can finish off anything, but I ain't no murderer.
>   Endless, lifeless, I can be heartless.
>   Changing a trap into a chunk can be seamless.
>   I can destroy things, just to make something new.
>   Can help connect things, to help a few.
>   I may be even, I may be odd, Or just the one who tells you the way.
>   Or I may be just the start or the end, or may be just a say.
>   Two of those non letter thingy arrive, things are blown up.
>   I play no role when the the things double up.

**What am I?**

Comment: I would answer "String operations"… well at least for half of it, but not all :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **Indicator** as in crosswords/wordplays. Starting with container(ear>part>fearsome), homophones(b>bee), deletion(behead,heartless,endless,finish off), anagram(trap>part>chunk), anagram(destroy>new), charades(join may be), letter sequences(even,odd), acrostic(start,end*). Also, I am not entirely sure but, two non letter could be &lit clues with ! > &!. And double def's hardly use indicators. The title was a hint I took.

**Explanations**

I can bury a part in fearsome.

> Container(ear>part>fearsome)

Can make the second letter fly, which is awesome.

> Homophones(b>bee)

I can behead, but I ain't no killer.

> Deletion(Behead)

Can finish off anything, but I ain't no murderer.

> Deletion(Finish Off)

Endless, lifeless, I can be heartless.

> Deletion(Endless, Lifeless, Heartless)

Changing a trap into a chunk can be seamless.

> Anagram(Trap $\rightarrow$ Part $\rightarrow$ Chunk)

I can destroy things, just to make something new.

> Anagram(Destroy a word to make a new one)

Can help connect things, to help a few.

> Charades(connecting words)

I may be even, I may be odd, Or just the one who tells you the way.
Or I may be just the start or the end, or may be just a say.

> Letter Sequences(start,end,even,odd) 
>  Homophones(Say)

Two of those non letter thingy arrive, things are blown up.

> &lit clues with "!" don't often have indicators.

I play no role when the the things double up.

> Double definitions don't have indicators most often or may be never.

Title : Pointing the right direction!

> Yes. They do point the right direction towards solving the clues.

Reference -

> http://www.crosswordunclued.com/2008/09/dictionary.html?m=1

Comment: Suggested edit to add spoilers on your answer.

Comment: Thank you. How do you do it? Apologies. I am new to site. If you can point me to the right guide, I can self learn.

Comment: Here is a link for help with the SE markdowns. Shows how to add italics, linebreaks, spoilers and so on. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help.

Comment: No worries. Still relatively new here myself. I will admit I kinda got a kick out of the lack of censorship (spoilers) considering you user name though...

Comment: +10 :-) That's brilliant. Welcome to Puzzling. Do you mind if I make some changes and accept it later?

Comment: Brilliant indeed. I kept getting hung up on C++ pointers =>. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

I assume we are looking for a word that has a B as a second letter. I tried:

> absinthe

And that works quiet well for just "I may be even, I may be odd, Or just the one who tells you the way."

> As percentage differs from 55-75% and this drink makes you quiet drunk, hallucinating..."

However, (and this is not the answer OP means!) another option is:

> (honey)bee?

I can bury a part in fearsome.

> Many people are afraid of you.

Can make the second letter fly, which is awesome.

> You are the second letter in the alphabet, a B. And you can fly.

I can behead, but I ain't no killer.

> **be**head; You don't sting people normally, only if you're made angry.

Can finish off anything, but I ain't no murderer.

> Not sure - perhaps a honeycomb?

Endless, lifeless, I can be heartless.

> **be** heartless; just looking for nectar from plants.

Changing a trap into a chunk can be seamless.

> **be** seamless; not sure

I can destroy things, just to make something new.

> Bees detect and destroy diploid drones after the eggs hatch.

Can help connect things, to help a few.

> Worker bees looking for nectar which is used as a source of water.

I may be even, I may be odd, Or just the one who tells you the way.

> **be** even, **be** odd; not sure

Or I may be just the start or the end, or may be just a say.

> **be** just the start; **be** just a say; not sure

Two of those non letter thingy arrive, things are blow up.

> Not sure

I play no role when the the things double up.

> B**ee** eeeeeee?

Comment: Nope. No where close. Sorry.

Comment: I knew it was not that easy ;) - I will continue thinking...

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> The letter E?

Pointing the right direction!

> East or 'E' is generally shown to the right side of the map.

I can bury a part in fearsome.

> Part buried in fearsome is 'EAR'

Can make the second letter fly, which is awesome.

> Can turn 'B' into a 'BEE'

I may be even, I may be odd, Or just the one who tells you the way.

> 'E' tells you the way when it refers to East.

Or I may be just the start or the end, or may be just a say.

> Start- 'ENTRY', or End- 'EXIT'

Two of those non letter thingy arrive, things are blown up.

> Referring to exponents? Or E=mc^2

Comment: Not anywhere close. But you found the some good things.